# Why does this Rust import need `self`?

Tags: rust

I have the following set of imports at the top of my program:

```
extern crate serde_bencode;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_bytes;
extern crate url;
extern crate url_serde;

use serde_bytes::ByteBuf;
use serde_bencode::de;
use serde_bencode::error::Result;
use serde_bencode::Error::{Custom, InvalidLength};
use self::url::{Url};
```

This program currently *does* compile. However, I don't understand why I need to write `self` on the `use self::url::{Url};` line. None of the other `use` statements need `self` - why does `url`?

For context, the snippet above is from a file called `file_reader.rs`, in a directory with the following structure:

```
roar/
    file_reader.rs
    main.rs
    lib.rs
```

Edit: I just noticed that if I add the line `extern crate url;` to `lib.rs`, then I don't need the `self`; however, I don't know *why* this step is necessary.

Comment: *at the top of my program* — what file is this code in?

Comment: Added more info/the directory structure.